# unable to load 2 xml elements

Tags: php, xml, laravel

i can only load 1 elemet $row. i tried to make a new element $api but it doen't load it in my view. but the input of the $api is saved perfectley in my xml file. ALso when i Do a vardump, the input data shows. but i can't figure out why its dosn't load.

Here is my Load function

```
 public function load()
{
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $dom->load('config.xml');

    //init
    $array = array();
    //get all form tags
    $rows = $dom->getElementsByTagName('row');
    $apis = $dom->getElementsByTagName('api');
    foreach($rows as $row){
        //get all field-tags from this form
        $fields = $row->getElementsByTagName('field');
        //create an empty element
        $element = array('row');
        //walk through the input elements of the current form element
        foreach($fields as $field){
            $name = $field->getAttribute('name');
            $value = $field->nodeValue;
            //add the data to element array
            $element[$name] = $value;
        }
        //add the element to your array
        $array[] = $element;
    }
    foreach($apis as $api){
        //get all field-tags from this form
        $fields = $api->getElementsByTagName('field');
        //create an empty element
        $element = array('api');
        //walk through the input elements of the current form element
        foreach($fields as $field){
            $name = $field->getAttribute('name');
            $value = $field->nodeValue;
            //add the data to element array
            $element[$name] = $value;
        }
        //add the element to your array
        $array[] = $element;

    }

    
    //print it
    $datas = $array;
```

//         var_dump($datas);die;

```
    return $datas;
}
```

Here is my view

```
@foreach ($datas as $data)
                    <tr id="data{{ $data['id'] }}">
                    <tr id="data{{ $data['api_id'] }}">
                        <td>
                            {{ $data['name'] }}<br>
                            <small>{{ $data['position'] }}</small>
                        </td>
                        <td>{{ $data['city'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $data['email'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $data['department'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $data,$api ?? ''['carname'] }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $data, $api ?? ''['age'] }}</td>
                        {{--                            <td><img src="{{ $data['avatar'] }}" height="60" alt="avatar"></td>--}}
                        <td>
                            @if ($data['status'] === '1')
                                <h4><p class="label label-success round">Masuk
                                    <p></h4>
                            @elseif ($data['status'] === '2')
```

please help me!

Comment: Where **exactly** does this code go wrong? And how is this related to Laravel?

Comment: it goed wrong with loading the xml in the font-end. it succes with the $row element. but when i try the same thing with new created $api element. i get the error undefined index:id.  i Use Laravel to create this app